# Find the position of a lowest difference between numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I've got two musical files: one lossless with little sound gap (at this time it's just silence but it could be anything: sinusoid or just some noise) at the beginning and one mp3:

```
In [1]: plt.plot(y[:100000])
Out[1]:
```

[image: Lossless file]

```
In [2]: plt.plot(y2[:100000])
Out[2]:
```

[image: mp3 file]

This lists are similar but not identical so I need to cut this gap, to find the first occurrence of one list in another with lowest delta error.

And here's my solution (5.7065 sec.):

```
error = []
for i in range(25000):
    y_n = y[i:100000]
    y2_n = y2[:100000-i]
    error.append(abs(y_n - y2_n).mean())
start = np.array(error).argmin()

print(start, error[start]) #23057 0.0100046
```

Is there any pythonic way to solve this?

**Edit:**
After calculating the mean distance between special points (e.g. where data == 0.5) I reduce the area of search from 25000 to 2000. This gives me reasonable time of 0.3871s:

```
a = np.where(y[:100000].round(1) == 0.5)[0]
b = np.where(y2[:100000].round(1) == 0.5)[0]

mean = int((a - b[:len(a)]).mean())
delta = 1000

error = []
for i in range(mean - delta, mean + delta):
...
```

Comment: What if we compare not the whole array but just most unique part of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) of the two signals.

This can be done easily using [`signal.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html) from the `scipy` library:

```
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np

# limit your signal length to speed things up
lim = 25000

# do the actual correlation
corr = scipy.signal.correlate(y[:lim], y2[:lim], mode='full')

# The offset is the maximum of your correlation array,
# itself being offset by (lim - 1):
offset = np.argmax(corr) - (lim - 1)
```

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690225/1525423) answer to a similar problem.

Comment: It's triple times slower than my solution: 18.4793s against 5.7065s :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's generate some data first

```
N = 1000
y1 = np.random.randn(N)
y2 = y1 + np.random.randn(N) * 0.05
y2[0:int(N / 10)] = 0
```

In these data, `y1` and `y2` are *almost* the same (note the small added noise), but the first 10% of `y2` are empty (similarly to your example)

We can now calculate the absolute difference between the two vectors and find the first element for which the absolute difference is below a sensitivity threshold:

```
abs_delta = np.abs(y1 - y2)
THRESHOLD = 1e-2
sel = abs_delta < THRESHOLD
ix_start = np.where(sel)[0][0]


fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1)
ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(y1, '-')
ax.set_title('y1')
ax.axvline(ix_start, color='red')
ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(y2, '-')
ax.axvline(ix_start, color='red')
ax.set_title('y2')

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(abs_delta)
ax.axvline(ix_start, color='red')
ax.set_title('abs diff')
```

[image: sample data plotted]

This method works if the overlapping parts are indeed "almost identical". You will have to think of smarter alignment ways if the similarity is low.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not quite my problem, you should change your `y2[0:int(N / 10)] = 0` to `y2 = np.hstack([np.zeros(int(N / 10)),y2])[:N]`

Comment: If you know that `y2` is essentially `y1`, except for the fact that its initial fraction is "quiet", then why can't you simply search for the point at which `y2` absolute value is larger than some threshold?

Comment: Because for me it really important to reduce delta error between tracks not just cut the trash (e.g. I don't mind if there's 5 second of silence in both files).

Comment: 1. locate the point at which the silence stops (`ix = np.where(np.abs(y2)>THRESHOLD)[0][0]`)

2. trim the arrays (`y2=y2[ix:]; y1=y1[ix:]`)

3. calculate the difference (`d=y1 - y2`)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is correlation. Here is a small example.

```
import numpy as np

equal_part = [0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -4, 5, 0]
y1 = equal_part + [0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -4, 5, 0]
y2 = [1, 2, 4, -3, -2, -1, 3, 2]+y1

np.argmax(np.correlate(y1, y2, 'same'))
```

Out:

```
7
```

So this returns the time-difference, where the correlation between both signals is at its maximum. As you can see, in the example the time difference should be 8, but this depends on your data...
Also note that both signals have the same length.

Comment: Yeah I somehow forgot about correlation but unfortunately your example isn't working neither:  `In [109]: np.correlate([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "same")

Out[109]: array([14, 26, 40, 30, 20])` But it should be second element not the third.